# Server clock runs fast - sometimes

Tags: ubuntu, time

I have 12.04 Ubuntu servers that make a radio link once per hour to send updates and sync clocks. The clocks all stray by about +/- 0.6 seconds per hour, which is expected based their crystal ppm.

The problem I have is that I have witnessed a period of 5 to 15 minutes where the clocks runs fast . I actually witnessed the clock run faster - ticking over at nearly double speed. From what I can work out the clock is running near double speed for ~10 minutes around 5am or 6am on a few random days per year.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Every step every hour is +/-0.6 seconds except:

```
21 Dec 11:48:19 STEP -702.605018 sec
20 Feb 05:50:03 STEP -598.327074 sec
20 Feb 06:50:03 STEP -597.584943 sec
20 Mar 05:50:36 STEP -565.132001 sec
20 Mar 06:50:37 STEP -565.148216 sec
 4 Apr 11:50:55 STEP -546.447274 sec
 4 Apr 14:50:55 STEP -546.137015 sec
17 Apr 05:51:09 STEP -532.402534 sec
17 Apr 06:51:09 STEP -532.105325 sec
15 May 05:51:39 STEP -502.149757 sec
15 May 06:51:40 STEP -502.046952 sec
25 Jul 05:52:32 STEP -448.393918 sec
21 Aug 05:52:51 STEP -429.532834 sec
```

The server it syncs to has never stepped its time more than 0.1S to UTC.

Comment: Is something _else_ on those machines setting the clock?

Comment: Pretty sure no. It would have to be setting the time almost every second - forward a second. I have seen the clock ticking over at about double speed. This is a on clean 12.04 server install, only running a program I coded in which I dont do anything with time, apart from sync once per hour.

Comment: They aren't virtual machines are they?

Comment: So, the custom code handles time syncing?  Not `ntpd` or `ntpdate`?